# Backticks evaluation problem in quoted command, in su -c, in heredoc, fed into 2 layers of ssh

Tags: linux, bash, quoting

I have the following chain of indirection:

```bsh
ssh -t root@host1 ssh host2 << EOF\nsu - user2 -c 'kill `cat ~/file_with_pid`'\nEOF
```

In the end what I need is just to kill a process (reading the pid from a file) on host2, as user2. I can't change much, except the part between single quotes

```bsh
'kill `cat ~/file_with_pid`'
```

therefore I cannot simply

```bsh
ssh user2@host2 'kill `cat ~/file_with_pid`'
```

My problem is that the home (`~` in the file's path) gets expanded to the wrong home. That probably has to do with when the backticks get evaluated (I'm not really sure when that is happening, due to the long chain of commands).

How can I change the part in single quotes to obtain what I want?

(Note: I cannot hardcode the home, since I might execute this on an arbitrary `host2` as user `user2`, and hence I want `user2`'s home to be determined every time).

Comment: I think it should work fine if you use `ssh -J host1 host2` or JumpHost definition in your `.ssh/config`. Made a quick test on my server and it worked well.

Comment: You mean substituting the part from the initial ssh until host2? Do you think that has anything to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @pLumo, you can get rid of some of the quoting hell by using the `-J` ("JumpHost") option of ssh:

```
ssh -J root@host1 root@host2 "su user2 -c 'kill \"\$(cat ~/file_with_pid)\"'"
```

Or, with a here-doc:

```
ssh -J root@host1 -T root@host2 <<'EOT'
su user2 -c 'kill "$(cat ~/file_with_pid)"'
EOT
```

Notice the `<<'EOT'` instead of `<<EOT`; quoting the end marker prevents variables, backticks, etc from being expanded in the here-doc.

The `-T` prevents ssh from allocating a pseudo-tty in general, and in this case it will prevent ssh from warning you that it hasn't allocated one. If for some reason you really need a pseudo-tty, use two `-t` options to force ssh to allocate one even when the *local* stdin is not a tty. And also put an `exit` in the here-doc:

```
ssh -J root@host1 -tt root@host2 <<'EOT'
su user2 -c 'kill "$(cat ~/file_with_pid)"'
exit
EOT
```

If you need to connect to another port instead of 22 on the jump-host, you should use the `-J user@host1:port` form; the `-p` option would apply to `host2`:

```
ssh -J root@host1:port1 -p port2 root@host2 "su user2 -c 'kill \"\$(cat ~/file_with_pid)\"'"
```

I don't know of any shortcut option which would allow you to use a different identity for the jump-host (as with `-i`); it seems that you have to use a configuration file for that.

---

In your example, `EOF\nsu` unquoted is just `EOFnsu`, not `EOF<newline>su` (and that will not work even if it were).

But redirecting the stdin of `ssh` (as a `<<` here-doc does) would have prevented any interactive authentication on the second host, so even that wouldn't have fixed your example.

Comment: 1. How does `-J` change the key verification? I'm getting a permission denied if I replace the 2 `ssh` with one `ssh -J`

2. In your first example, why are you escaping `$`?

3. I'm not sure about the tty part. I need to receive the output of the command back, during the command execution. (E.g. if I `ls; sleep 2; ls` I want to see the result of `ls`, then again after 1 second, then the command should exit).

4. What are you referring to with "that will not work even if it were" in the EOF part?

5. Not sure what you mean with the last part. Could you elaborate?

Comment: __1.__ `-J` is using the same identity for both `host1` and `host2`. As already mentioned in the answer, there's no command line option to use different identities -- you have to use a config file (or maybe there is, but I wasn't able to figure it out) __2.__ I'm escaping it because otherwise the `$(...)` command substitution (~ same as backticks) would be expanded on the _local_ host. __4.-5.__ Your example is unsalvageable, sorry. Why your approach of using ssh to start another ssh to start su could probably be done, it will turn into something mad with up to 10 backslashes ;-)

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately I need different identities. Have you seen my other questions? (I edited the comment after publishing it too early)

Comment: No, I've only seen this. You can easily use different identities with `Match` or `Host` blocks in the `~/.ssh/config`, see the `ssh_config(5)` manpage. Also, you can use other config file than `~/.ssh/config` via `ssh -F file ...`.

Comment: For the tty part, `ls; sleep 2; ls` should work even without a tty (since they're separate commands, each will flush its stdio buffer upon exiting).

Comment: Ok, I'm using 2 ssh and quoted marker for the here-doc. This is the smallest change that makes my code work (disallowing the local evaluation of the backquoted part in the command). Thanks!